# Ruby Desktop Applications

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to create an entire application in ruby and run as an exe file in windows, or as an application on any OS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One important thing to realize about ruby2exe is that it is not compatible with Ruby 1.9 and has not been updated in quite some time. **I would recommend [Ocra](https://rubygems.org/gems/ocra).** I have used it myself, and it is compatible with Ruby 1.9 and still being updated.

Answer (score 6):

A ruby script can be a full application yes, there's no reason it can't.

If I understand what you meant though, you want to compile a ruby script into a standalone executable? If that's what you meant, you could check out ruby2exe.

Another possibility, something that you might want to check out, is [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/). You can use Ruby and web languages to create totally cross-platform Desktop applications.

Comment: @JC Leyba one thing to know is that ruby2exe isn't compatible with Ruby 1.9

Answer (score 2):

Sure. There're a couple of frameworks for these purposes. For instance, 'shoes' (search at github). Also, jRuby has a direct access to Java's classes, including Java Swing.

Answer (score 1):

In a try to give some **update** to this thread:

Certainly, there are ways to do desktop apps using ruby, but all of them seems a little outdated.
NodeJs based projects are gaining a lot of buzz and contribution this days.
Projects like [Brackets-Shell](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell) and [Node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) are the most prominent in the field.
The approach is not so difficult to get, yo can use the ExpressJS framework (similar to Sinatra but in Javascript) and get similar results.

Definitely you should try both of them, or at least read the README on the github pages, there are a ton of projects that fits perfectly in this approach.
Personally i have tried Node-Webkit, and the result is amazing, very fast and you can reuse all your web skills.

Comment: Can you run ruby in any of those frameworks? I really want to have html5+css front-end, but there are some ruby gems I want to use for data processing

Comment: @Cort3z Nope, you can't. They are based in NodeJS, that said, you can use almost any node package and i'm pretty sure that there are a lots that can fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Developing with Ruby is possible. I found [limelight](http://limelight.8thlight.com/sparkle) interesting.