# Ruby for cross-platform desktop applications?

Tags: ruby, qt, wxwidgets

Please share you experience building desktop applications with Ruby programming language. What GUI toolkits have you used? How have you packed everything into one installer? What troubles have you spotted?

I saw few articles about using Ruby for desktop, but in teory everything is always great. I would like to know about real-world applications build with ruby.

Comment: I've used Ocra along with wxRuby, and it worked pretty well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372988/ruby-desktop-applications

Answer (score 2):

you can check this out

[Non-trivial desktop apps that use Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129383/non-trivial-desktop-apps-that-use-ruby)

i used redcar & its available as a Gem