# 'deploying' a ruby script with gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

i've written several Ruby scripts that work together to from a ***console application***.
These scripts are written on an Ubuntu platform, but I want to be able to run them from a Windows platform as well.

The problem I'm currently facing is porting over all the gems. I've downloaded sources of most gems and made some bug fixes on them, but is it possible to package them for example with my scripts so they're available?
I'm thinking a bit DLL like here as Windows does.

I can probably add a readme file, stating which gems are required and where/how to obtain them, but it would be easier if I could package them.

Comment: maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372988/ruby-desktop-applications/4373893#4373893 If you are wanting to run something on both Ubuntu and Windows, you may need a better solution, but if you have access to Windows to package everything, that should work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could look at http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/index.html which does some packaging for ruby application (including the ruby interpreter, too)

You could also build a gem with your script in it along with all needed gems directly inside the gem. Provided their licences allow you to do that, it could be a reasonable solution ( Gem supports platform flavoured gems http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#platform )