# Is it a way to distribute compound Ruby scripts like PHAR in PHP/JAR in Java/EGG in Python?

Tags: ruby

In my work it's often to distribute scripts to other departments in a company, contractors etc. If a script is a single .rb / .php / .jar / .py file it's easy: all i need is to somehow supply this file to a person and he just double clicks it to execute. But if script is complex (big), writing it as a single file is not very good from programmer's point of view - so complex scripts are created as a number of files with something like "main" file that starts a script. And where is a problem with distributing such scripts to non-programmers: they need to copy an entire folder containing all files, locate the main file and double click it. This is much harder to non-programmers than just double clicking a single file :(. Really.

PHP, Java and Python offers a solution for such distribution problems. I can just pack all files into ".phar", ".jar" or ".egg" file and push this file to end users - double clicking it will execute a script (or entering it's name in a console if script is command-line). Same simplicity as with single script file.

Does something like this exists for Ruby? I have checked the 'gem' mechanics that seems to me very common to python 'egg' - but it seems that 'gems' are not suited to be executed as a 'script', they are for installation only :(.

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: This might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372988/ruby-desktop-applications/4373893#4373893

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use JRuby in combination with Rawr:

http://rawr.rubyforge.org/

To quote the docs: "*With Rawr, a simple, pre-generated configuration file turns your code into an executable jar, a .exe for Windows, and a .app for OS X.*"

Comment: Thanks. This is a possible solution, but a number of abstraction layers used kinda scares me :). Such solution can lead to situations where ruby script created and debugged on developer computer and resulting java executable will be two very different things with different behaviors :)