# Ruby 2 Exe tool

Tags: ruby, windows, exe

Anyone knows which tools can be used to make independent exe - file from ruby - script?
I tried both exerb and rubyscript2exe. But they are obsolete and don't work properly(

exerb can't properly make exe from script file which uses "require net/http" :-(
rubyscipt2exe does nothing, just nothing :-(

Comment: Here is the exact same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372988/ruby-desktop-applications

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Ocra](https://rubygems.org/gems/ocra)?

It was the first result(s) for [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=package+ruby+scripts+as+executable&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=1&tbas=0&biw=1095&bih=716&prmd=imvns&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ei=Mj_8TuDlCoTagAeP5PG1Ag&ved=0CAwQpwUoBg6) (limited to results in the past year, which is a must for many, if not most, Ruby-related searches).

Answer (score 3):

I also wanted to generate .exe file from my ruby script several months ago, and exerb and rubyscript2exe didn't work for me, either. Finally, I decided to use [ocra](http://ocra.rubyforge.org/), and I hope my solution can help you.

1. gem install ocra
2. ocra your_ruby_script.rb

if you are lucky enough, ocra should generate `your_ruby_script.exe` after step2. However, I was not lucky, and I faced the following error messages when the first time I used ocra:

```
Invalid gemspec in [c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/ocra-1.3.0.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-06-19 00:00:00.000000000Z "
Invalid gemspec in [c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/win32-autogui-0.5.0.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-17 00:00:00.000000000Z" 1.8.8
```

Don't be disappointed. Just edit these files

`c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/ocra-1.3.0.gemspec`
`c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/win32-autogui-0.5.0.gemspec`

change

`"2011-06-19 00:00:00.000000000Z "` into `"2011-06-19"`

`"2011-08-17 00:00:00.000000000Z"` into `"2011-08-17"`

redo step 2 after editing these files, and everything should be great now.