# How to produce a self contained Ruby "executable"?

Tags: ruby

I have some simple Ruby scripts that I would like to distribute to coworkers. They are not very complex, but they involve many files and a directory architecture, thus I would like to be able to automatically "group" all of that in a single file to ease the distribution.

Is there any Ruby tool that would automate that ? I don't need a binary, that can be another Ruby script.

Comment: What about good ol' zipping? :)

Comment: Sometimes, we should avoid thinking about gems.

Comment: have you considered creating a gem?

Comment: If you need to distribute it to people without a Ruby installation, then look at my answer here- http://stackoverflow.com/q/4372988/366051

Answer (score 1):

You can use ocra. It will package your script into an executable.  It is windows-only though.  http://ocra.rubyforge.org/